# Gitlab CI/CD - One task at the same time

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

i want each task to run one at a time after the previous one finishes. I have;

```
deploy_1:
  script:
       - scp -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR/script.sh ubuntu@domain1.tld.pl:/root/script.sh
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master

deploy_2:
  script:
       - scp -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR/script.sh ubuntu@domain2.tld.pl:/root/script.sh
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
```

and more.. and there are two tasks running at the same time. In runner config:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "myrunner"
  url = "https://XXXXXX/"
  token = "XXXXX"
  limit = 1
  request_concurrency = 1
```

Any ideas?

I have to one by one because i get timeouts.

Answer (score 2):

You could add

```
needs: ["deploy_1"]
```

To your deploy_2 job. It will chain deploy_2 to deploy_1